# Standing orders or recurring orders

Tags: orders, magento-1.9

Is there a way of setting up an order on a customers profile that will automatically send after a certain time period. For example a order that will automatically dispatch every 2 weeks, like a standing order.

Or even an extension which knows how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: @ Adam Allen : is it solve your issue.

Comment: Any idea you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an additional field to sales_flat_order table after order creation and set it's value to 1 if it is a standing order.

Then you could set up a cron that fetches a list of all orders that have this value set to 1 and are exactly two weeks old. In the cron you would then re-create these orders. Have a look at Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController :: reorderAction() on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the Recurring Profiles feature in Magento? If you need to charge the customer for each order then you could using Paypal, if not you might be able to do an initial fee and then the recurring orders with a total of 0 (I've not actually tested but can't see why it wouldn't work